# How to use two different imageView and get pictures from camera roll differently

Tags: ios, swift2

I followed this [tutorial](http://fvimagination.hubpages.com/hub/Access-Photo-Camera-and-Library-in-Swift), everything went well until I try to use two different imageView on the same viewController and change the two pictures as I want.

I try to use sender to know which one called the camera roll:

```
// --MARK: Image picker delegate
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, sender: AnyObject) {
    backgroundAccount.image = image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

But that didn't worked at all. The delegate method was not called at all.

I would like to do the same as FaceBook a profile picture and a background picture.

Any idea?

EDIT:

This will update background:

```
    // --MARK: Image picker delegate
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    backgroundAccount.image = image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

And this will update profile picture:

```
    // --MARK: Image picker delegate
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    profile.image = image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

How can I change both as I don't know, in my delegate who call it.

Comment: i download the the tutorial from the link that you follow.. and check in simulator it works and delegate you said which not call is also called.. so if you not download the sample code then download that and run and check i think you made minor mistake.. in demo they add 
class ViewController: UIViewController,
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate

Comment: Sorry, I made a wrong edit, this is now correct. The sender: AnyObject don't work.

Comment: Yes but That's not the question, please take a look at the question. I want 2 ImageView in one ViewController, and change both with different photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you assigned the `delegate` property of the UIImagePickerController instance to your view controller? It is must for you to get a delegate call back on `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:`.

**EDIT:** Post OP edit: You need to keep track of a `bool` at class level and set if before you present your image picker. For instance, declare a `bool` named `setProfilePicture` and set it to `true` just before you present you picker view for profile picture. This could be a specific button tap or something that let you know to set a picture on profile. Now, set your picture in `didFinishPickingImage` like this:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    if setProfilePicture {
       profile.image = image
    } else {
       backgroundAccount.image = image
    }

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question, it would be better for you to understand now. BTW I'm not fluent at all on Swift, what do you mean by `Have you assigned the delegate property of the UIImagePickerController instance to your view controller?` ?

Comment: So, you might have created an instance of `UIImagePickerController ` in your code something like `let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()` or connecting a global variable like this in storyboard. You must set that `imagePicker.delegate = self` for you to get a call back on above said method.

Comment: Yes I have a `let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()` in my function `func backgroundPictureTapButton(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)`. But I also have the same on my `func profilePictureTapButton(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)`. I don't understand what `imagePicker.delegate = self` will do, can you explain me please?

Comment: That will set your view controller as delegate of image picker. In simple term when image picker will be done capturing a photo it will call that method on its delegate. So you should be calling your self as delegate for image picker.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I have no problem to get pictures, just if I want to put a profile picture I will not be able to put a background picture as I have only one `Delegate`  and I have no way to know which picture I want to update.

Comment: Check out my edited post. That may help you fixing your issue.

Comment: Ho god, I'm sooo dumb, why I didn't think about that. Thank you sooo much @Abhinav

Answer (score 0):

This delegate is deprecated in objc and it doesn't appear in swift header. You should try to use this delegate instead `optional public func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])`

You can find the image from this:
`let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out;

Assign tags to your imagePicker controllers and when the IBAction is triggered to invoke camera, get sender.tag and assign it to a public variable. In my example I asking it to tagPictureSource.

extend your view controller to the delgate ***UIImagePickerControllerDelegate*** and use something like follows.

```
extension imageViewController : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[String: AnyObject]) {

    var temp: UIImage!
    temp = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    if (tagPictureSource == 1 ) {
        imageview1.image = temp
    } else if (tagPictureSource == 2 ) {
        imageview2.image = temp
    } else if (tagPictureSource == 3) {
        imageview3.image = temp
    }
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It didn't work at all :/ And I can't get my image using this delegate. I miss the `didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!`